# EVO 3D screen size/DPI issue

Tags: android

One of my beta testers has an EVO 3D and reported that my app draws
things (some custom widgets) too small. Upon further inspection of
both my app's log data and the output from the `glInfo` app, I realized
why: the phone is reporting an incorrect DPI. Here's some of the
output from glInfo:

```
Display Resolution
  Pixels = 540 x 960
  DPIs = 159.48837 x 160.42105
```

Now do the math. If you calculate the diagonal size of the screen from
these numbers, it comes out to **6.88 inches.** The true size is 4.3
inches. What could be going on here? Is this a problem with the phone?
It's relatively new, so this could be a possibility. I'm at a loss...

Any ideas? My app needs a correct DPI to calculate the correct size to display some of its elements. Is only this guy's phone messed up, or do I need to find a workaround?

Comment: He did say that he had an app installed, Spare Parts, to enable "Compatibility mode" in order to fix an older app that was only taking up 2/3 of his screen. He has since reverted that setting (confirmed because the older app is back to its old behavior,) and after a restart of the phone nothing changed in the DPI.

Comment: Update: It seems the problem magically fixed itself...